# Excel - dropdown and formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

For example: I have a dropdown list in A1 with a couple of options to select (day, week, month). And in the same sheet in B1 I have one "month". Is there a way (a formula) which can type in which will select a proper option from the dropdown based on B1 "month"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add an example of what would be in A1 and what in B1 and explain the reason for your expected result. Edit your question to do that. Do not put that clarification into a comment. Post a comment when you're done with editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

,How about :

```
IF(B1="xxxx",calculation on B,IF(B1="yyyy",2nd calculation on B)
```

or

```
IF(B1="xxxx","text for B",IF(B1="yyyy","text 2 for B","check"))
```

Difficult to work out what you want though, but those should point you in the right direction...